# Converting "wrong" MySQL encoding from old server to correct UTF-8 on new server

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I set up a web project on a web server with apparently wrong encoding. But somehow (I really don't know why), we figured how we had to deal with it and the encoding worked for us.
But now we moved the data to a new server with a correctly set up UTF8 database and surprise, the encoding is wrong.
How can we "correct" the data, is there any best practice?

**Example**
old server: http://www.orat.io/stmt/200
new server: http://www.firefile.net/stmt/200

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This actually happens in practice - I've seen it sometimes :-) What usually happens:

- database is in `utf-8`
- input/output is in encoding1 - say it is `iso-8859-2` (i.e. the meta-charset in HTML)
- but, because the previous admin didn't know how to properly set the database connection encoding (this is the charset which is specified using `set names` SQL command), the database connection is configured *as if* the input/output is in different encoding2 - say `iso-8859-1` - default on many linux systems.

To get the correct data out of the database, you must access it in the same erroneous way as you did before - e.g. for the example above,  set `iso-8859-1` encoding but in fact get the `iso-8859-2`. Everything "works" until someone starts to access the database correctly.

You have not provided enough detail about what is encoding1/encoding2 in your case and you probably don't know it. So, either look at the old setup or try to figure out by trial and error.

**The easiest way to re-code your database** is probably to do `mysqldump` in encoding2, then claim it's encoding1 (just put the `set names encoding1` at the beginning of sql file) and import the database into an empty one by source-ing the sql file. All database fields of course stay in `utf-8` all the time.

Be careful and use PHPMyAdmin as an independent tool to see the "real" state of the database. :-) Good luck with this rebus.

Comment: mysqldump is the way to go. Rather than PHPMyAdmin I recommend the mysql command line for this. PHPMyAdmin's encoding display depends also on the browser settings which are an additional error source.

Comment: @AlexMonthy there are no "browser settings" that could cause an error of PHPMyAdmin. It all runs in utf-8. But I agree that `mysqldump` (not `mysql`) is better for backup; I proposed PHPMyAdmin just for check.